# Adding BrowserSync to gulpfile.js

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-browser-sync

I have the following code in gulpfile.js file

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src('assets/src/css/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src('assets/src/js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'scripts']);

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('src/css/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

I want to add browserSync to this file. The example [here](https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp) is containing just the sass plugin. I need to add the following

- Uglify & concat the JS and CSS files.
- BrowserSync to update my html files.

How can I implement the above?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
I have corrected the grammatical errors and typos in the question for better readability. I have also ask the question in point form so that it would be easier to answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add `.pipe(browserSync.stream())` in the task in the place you would like it to take place.

This should probably be the last action.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src('assets/src/js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/dist/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can show me how my gulpfile.js sholud be after adding this code?

Comment: @ronjacob Replace your `'scripts'` task with the one in the answer.